# Software for Bluetooth hearing aids

Tags: bluetooth, accessibility

Does anyone have experience with Linux software that works for Bluetooth hearing aids?  Lots of hearing aids do have such software. but it's usually only for Apple. And of course the software is usually for a particular brand of hearing aids,though it might work for some other brands also.  Mine are TruHearing.

I don't know for certain  they're being picked up, but they can communicate with each other, and Bluetooth Manager Manager is picking up several devices. Unfortunately only my headphones can't be identified through the **info** command in Bluetooth Manager.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444271&highlight=hearing+aids

Comment: I've learned from my audiologist that TruHearing is actually a "house brand".  The real name is Signia.